# Round up the last digit of whole numbers

Tags: math, integer, numbers, rounding, number-formatting

I have a number on which I need to round up the last digit, either to 0 or 5.

Examples:

1. From `0, 1, 2` to `0`, for example 12 -> 10
2. From `3, 4, 5, 6, 7` to `5`, like 37 -> 35
3. And from `8, 9, 0` to `0`, again like 59 -> 60

I tried `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` but those are not working. As I've found out those are for floating point numbers and can not be used for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.ceil` and `Math.floor` are for floating-point numbers (like `Double`s). There's no built-in function for what you want to do, but this should work

```
public static int round(int original) {
    if original % 10 <= 2 {
        return original - (original % 10)
    } else if original % 10 <= 7 {
        return original - (original % 10) + 5
    }
    return original - (original % 10) + 10
}
```

If you want it to work with negative numbers, use this:

```
public static int round(int original) {
    if original % 10 <= 2 {
        return original - (original % 10)
    } else if original % 10 <= 7 {
        return original - (original % 10) + 5
    } else if original % 10 <= 9 {
        return original - (original % 10) + 10
    } else if original % 10 >= -2 {
        return original - (original % 10)
    } else if original % 10 >= -7 {
        return original - (original % 10) - 5
    }
    return original - (original % 10) - 10
}
```

Clearly, you can't just copy & paste this code, because you'll need to put it in a class and possibly change the visibility and `static`ness (the `public static`) part.

To use it, call `int rounded = round(input)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just edited my answer so that it will also work with negative inputs, if you want that

Comment: Also, if this worked for you, please click the check mark to mark this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

To round number `int n` to the nearest multiple of 5:

```
((n + 2) / 5) * 5;
```

No need for complex logic.

More generically, to round `int n` to a multiple of `int m`

```
((n + (m/2)) / m) * m;
```

If you want to work with negative numbers too, it becomes:

```
((n + (n >= 0 ? 2 : -2)) / 5) * 5;

((n + (n >= 0 ? (m/2) : -(m/2)) / m) * m;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple function that rounds to whatever value you want, it takes two arguments, one of them being a number to round. The other one is (in your case it's 5) precision of rounding.

```
public static double roundTo(double toRound, double precision){
    double holder = toRound/precision;
    int result = (int) Math.round(holder);
    return result*precision;
}
```

Comment: make precision param as method local variable and set it to 5. Now u will use with one input. Decorate according to your needs , it will improve you. Dont wait absolute answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil` / `Math.floor` round floating point numbers to the nearest integer number. They simply cannot do what you want, which is to find some nearest multiple for an integer.

There are various approaches you can take to tackle this problem. It's homework, I assume? The point is not to find a library call to do it as a one-liner (it helps that I'm pretty sure no such library call exists out of the box), the point is to write some basic code to do it.

Here's one way:

You can obtain the last digit with `x % 10` (which is x modulo 10. Note that `-15 % 10` is `-5`, not `5`), and then use a `switch` construct or a few `if`/`else if` statements to do the right thing based on the last digit.

or a trickier way:

When you do division on 2 integers in java, the result is always rounded to an integer, by way of just lopping off the bits after the comma (so for positive numbers, it rounds down). One way to end up with a number whose last digit is always 0 or 5, is to divide by 5, and multiply by 5 again. But you do need to figure out a strategy to ensure that, say, `13`, becomes `15` and not `10`, so you'd have to add something before you start dividing and multiplying by 5. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how to do this and what to add.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method to achieve that. You have to code it yourself.

An approach could be to compute mod 10 and add the difference:

```
int customRound(int n){
    int diff, mod = n % 10;

    if(mod < 3) diff = 0;
    else if(mod < 8) diff = 5;
    else diff = 10;

    return n - mod + diff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact that is rounding to the nearest 5-fold.
Rounding half-up.

```
n == 5f + r      where f, r < 5, f, r ints >= 0
  f = n / 5
  r = n % 5

r == 0, 1, 2 round down, rest round up
```

With this you should be able create a solution.